# C# - How can I block the typing of a letter on a key press?

Tags: c#, winforms, input, block, letter

I have a textbox with a OnKeyPress event. In this textbox I wish to input only numbers, and for some specific letters like t or m, I would want to execute a code without that letter being typed in the textbox. Small sample of what I am trying to do:

```
 //OnKeyPressed:
 void TextBox1KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.T || e.KeyCode == Keys.M) Button1Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

This unfortunately does not prevent the input of the letter..

Comment: What `Button1Click` does? you need to use `e.Handled = true;` here!!

Comment: Are you in Win form or WPF?

Comment: e.Handled did not work. Used SuppressKeyPress as Raluca said.

Comment: instead of calling `Button1Click(this, EventArgs.Empty)`, why not use `Button1.PerformClick()`?

Comment: Note that someone may still *paste* T and M into the textbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the SuppressKeyPress property from KeyEventArgs to true, like below:

```
private void TextBox1KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.T || e.KeyCode == Keys.M)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        Button1Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always run the TryParse on the keyDown event so as to validate as the data gets entered. It saves the user an additional UI interaction.

```
private void TextBox1KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int i;

        string s = string.Empty;

        s += (char)e.KeyValue;

         if (!(int.TryParse(s, out i)))
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
        else if(e.KeyCode == Keys.T || e.KeyCode == Keys.M)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            Button1Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }             
    }
```

Comment: Very useful on checking if number. Raluca provided the first answer on SuppressKey so that will stay as my answer